# MPAndroid - snapping x position when scrolling

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

After few hours of trying I'm looking for some hints on how to add snap-scroll mechanism to MPAndroid. Basically I want the 5 visible bars to align so they are fully visible and centered. I now imported the library source code because it looks like there's no other way to change the code in computeScroll (BarLineChartTouchListener).

Edit:
To clarify - I'm showing around 20 bars but chart is zoomed so user can scroll horizontally. What bothers me it is not getting aligned automatically so first visible bar might be clipped in half. I'm looking for snapping effect where it will round the position to the nearest multiplication of the bar width, leaving 5 fully visible bars.

Comment: more explanation to your problem would be helpful.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin - Sorry for that. I added explanation so hopefully it's now easier to see where my problem is.

Comment: `chart.moveViewTo(...)`? maybe?

Comment: @PhilippJahoda - I tried that - it jumps straight to the position, no animation. I think to make it look like smooth snapping I need to have animation. Thanks for the response. I'll have to analyse further classes like MoveViewJob and come up with modification.

Comment: @PhilippJahoda - any chance I could ask you for an explanation of the recommended way of adding this feature? With all the events listeners, gestures, matrix handling - I find it trick. Unless you don't fully get what the effect I'm looking for should looks like - then let me know and I'm happy to explain better.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up adding the following function in BarLineChartBase.java. I know it's far from elegant, but seems to do the job. It's limited to targetApi > 11, because of the ValueAnimator. For lower API (which I don't cater for) you might need to have a look at nineoldandroids or some other animation loop technique.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void alignX() {
        int count = this.getValueCount();
        int xIndex = this.getLowestVisibleXIndex() + Math.round( (this.getHighestVisibleXIndex() - this.getLowestVisibleXIndex()) / 2.0f );
        float xsInView = this.getXAxis().getValues().size() / this.getViewPortHandler().getScaleX();
        Transformer mTrans = this.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        float[] pts = new float[] { xIndex - xsInView / 2f, 0 };
        mTrans.pointValuesToPixel(pts);
        final Matrix save = new Matrix();
        save.set(this.getViewPortHandler().getMatrixTouch());
        final float x = pts[0] - this.getViewPortHandler().offsetLeft();
        final int frames = 20;
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator().ofInt(0, frames);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(500);
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            int prev = -1;
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                if( (int) animation.getAnimatedValue() > prev ) {
                    save.postTranslate( -x / (float)frames, 0);
                    BarLineChartBase.this.getViewPortHandler().refresh(save, BarLineChartBase.this, true);
                }
                prev = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.start();
}
```

I trigger it at the end of `computeScroll` function in `BarLineChartTouchListener`.

I kept names of variables as I copied code from functions like `MoveViewJob`, `ViewPortHandler` etc. Since it's only aligning in x axis - I removed Y axis calculations and used zeros instead. Any optimizations welcome, especially from the author @PhilippJahoda.